# Meaning of the term "instaciate"/"instatiate" in computer programming

Tags: meaning, terminology, technical, programming, computing

What does this word mean?

> [instaciate](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=instaciate), otherwise [instatiate](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=instatiate)

It's not in any of my dictionaries, but there are a few too many occurrences of this word in programming communities and [across](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&rlz=1CAHPZY_enUS716US716&q=instatiate&nfpr=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwij0Prr05jfAhXHqlkKHTYjDTgQvgUIKygB&biw=1536&bih=706) the [Internet](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&rlz=1CAHPZY_enUS716US716&biw=1536&bih=706&ei=wCIQXI2FK8iAvQTQ-63wBw&q=instaciate&oq=instaciate&gs_l=psy-ab.3...18711.18718..18723...0.0..0.0.0.......0....1..gws-wiz.befo23s4wK8) for me to believe that these people all really mean "instantiate."

*Bonus: Argue for a correct spelling.*

Comment: I think you are underestimating how, uh, *interestingly* people can spell English words, especially since a great many programmers aren't native English speakers. Your own provided links show people spelling words including "authomatically", "compilier", "it's characteristics", and one person who spelled the word in question both "instanciating" and "instaciate".

Comment: Programmers can make spelling mistakes too. The fact that *kernal* has lasted for decades is evidence. The intended word is *instantiate*

Comment: Well, if the majority of English writers are not native speakers (which is now the case), and the majority of programmers aren't either (which is probably the case, but not provably so), then the next question is when does the word become "correctly spelled" as _instatiate_? And why does it make a difference how it's spelled, anyway? That was always for the convenience of printers; there's no benefit to uniform spelling for the reader or the writer, especially now that Alexa can spell better than you ever could.

Comment: Looking briefly at your links, it's clear that "instantiate" was intended.  Either that or the bots have their own spelling scheme.

Comment: That could happen, @John.  Alternately, there could be a distinction worth preserving.  *To instantiate* means to create an example, as when we instantiate a discrete object from an abstract class description.  At a glance, *instatiate* looks like an adjective meaning *possessing value*, as when a primitive variable (which was perhaps never instantiated) has become subject to a valid assignment.  On the job, I care about differences like these.

Comment: @JohnLawler A lot of information science problems become magnitudinally bigger problems when you lose uniform spelling. An ounce of prevention, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **instantiate**, *verb*
>   in·​stan·​ti·​ate | \in-ˈstan(t)-shē-ˌāt
>   instantiated; instantiating
>   *transitive verb*
>
> : to represent (an abstraction) by a concrete instance
>   *heroes instantiate ideals*
>   <sub>https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/instantiate</sub>

After reading more than a handful of the Stack Overflow posts that you linked in your question, I can confidently say that they are all misspelling ***instantiate***.